# Jquery Scroll not firing when using

Tags: javascript, html

So when I scroll down the page it will not work at all when I am using bootstrap it just doesn't work but when I use website with just that js and html & css no `<head>` tags or anything it will work. My code is below.

I don't know what I can do to fix this. I've tried for about 3 hours trying to make it work but no matter what I do it wont work even if I remove the `add`class and `remove` class and put a `console.log` it wont even work. My friend uses the same js for his website and it works but I dont know what it is on my website that makes it different. We use the same jquery version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

        <link rel="icon" href="#" type="image/png">
        <title>PrismPanel | Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/style.css?v=0.1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              if($(this).scrollTop() !== 0) {
                $('.navbar').addClass('scrolled');
              } else {
                $('.navbar').removeClass('scrolled');
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery()` instead of `$`?

Comment: I have and it didn't work still I have tried multiple different ways to do this with jquery without it and no matter what I do anything having to do with scrolling doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please, fix the title: "Jquery Scroll not firing when using ...". When using what?

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you? I just replaced bootstrap.css source.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4e73gs8/

Because in this fiddle that works. 
Maybe something wrong is with your bootstrap.css file?

Comment: It was with my style.css file I had `overflow-x: hidden !important` in my css file on `body, html` Thank you for the help!